# Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend with Angular Universal and Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-universal

I am trying to perform a simple request to the Firestore on the server-side (Angular Universal runned with `firebase serve`):

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
     this.afs.doc<any>('myData').valueChanges().subscribe(resp => console.log(resp));
}
```

And I am running into issue with connection to the Firestore:

`error: [2019-01-06T12:26:14.371Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.5.9): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.`

- @angular ver: ^6.1.10
- @angular/fire ver: ^5.1.1
- firebase ver: ^5.7.2

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Kaspersky antivirus on your development machine check this issue : [Issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1190)

Turning off the antivirus program might help you in that case . 
Possible workarounds : 
- first and most important : you must check if your firestore connection details are valid and if your app is really trying to connect to the database .
- try logging the firestore errors with : firebase.firestore.setLogLevel('debug') . Then you will be able to give a detailed log about your issue , which will help resolving it.
- are you able to access the database from the same machine in firebase console  ? 
- are you serving a --prod build ? If not try it and see if the issue goes away .

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. From the browser (on the same machine) request works..